# Python rpy2.robjects having trouble with non ASCII characters

Tags: python, r, utf-8, decoding, rpy2

I'm new to Python and ran into some troubles when working with non ASCII characters like german Umlaute 'ä, ö, ü'.
I have the following test setup:

A Python (version: 3.6) script which calls an R (version: 3.4.1) script via rpy2.robjects:

**Python script:**

```
#!/Python/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Set environment variables
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHOME']    = 'C:/Python'
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']    = 'C:/Python/lib/site-packages'
os.environ['R_HOME']        = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1'
os.environ['R_USER']        = 'C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/rpy2'

# Import modules
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

# Call R script
robjects.r('''source('C:/Apache24/htdocs/Test/RScripts/Test.R')''')

# Get R variables
rpyNor  = robjects.r['normal']
rpyUml  = robjects.r['umlaute']
pyUml   = 'äöü'


print('Normal:', rpyNor[0])
print('Umlaute:', rpyUml)
print('PyUml:', pyUml)
```

**R script:**

```
normal  <- "aou"
umlaute <- "äöü"
```

Now my Python script produces the following output:

```
Normal: aou
Umlaute: [1] "äöü"

PyUml: äöü
```

But I can not access the `rpyUml[0]` object to get rid of the unwanted <s>[1] "</s> äöü <s>"</s> part of the output. When I `print(rpyUml[0])` it just throws a decoding error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I don't understand what the problem here is. I thought I got it covered by the `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the 2nd line of my script?

---

*Bonus question:*

I'm working in eclipse pydev and the script won't run properly in a pydev console when reaching the statement to call the R script it then throws a decoding error. Is there a way to also make it executable line by line and not just as a whole script? Obviously the script can run as a whole because of the `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` statement at the beginning, but that doesnt apply when being executed line by line. Would be great if this can also be done.

---

By the way, I'm working on a windows Server 2012 R2 pc if that adds something to the clarity of the problem.

Comment: I'd be suspicious that the data from the R script; the error suggests it might be encoded as cp1252.  So see if doing `rpyUml  = robjects.r['umlaute'].decode('cp1252')` makes a difference.

Comment: Just tried it, but python throws me an error `AttributeError: 'StrVector' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: In that case the best solution is probably to get your R script to encode the text as UTF-8 before handing it over to Python.  I don't know how to do this (I'm not an R programmer), but the docs [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/source.html) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html) look relevant.

Comment: Aparently I have managed to get the problem under control. You were right in suspecting that the R script invoked the trouble. I have found that the Test.R file itself was encoded in `iso-8859-1`. Replacing it by creating a new file in Notepad++ with `utf-8` encoding and same content/name solved it for me.
However, something strange persits: When I let python print a webpage with the varables, only the tag `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">` will display the umlauts correct and I'm left buffled why `utf-8` won't do the same...

Comment: I think that's moving into being a new question, but as a first step I'd take a look at the repr of 'äöü' in the interpreter; latin-1 is b'\xe4\xf6\xfc', utf-8 is b'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'.At least then you know what you're dealing with.